# Can we say that $ \{x_n \} $ admits a convergent subsequence?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a banach space with separable  dual $X^{*}$.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence of $X$.

Can we say that $ \{x_n \} $ admits a convergent subsequence ?

Comment: Consider for example an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space...

Comment: I did not understand your answer sir.  can you explain me a little?

Comment: If $(x_n)$ is an orthonormal basis for a separable Hilbert space then $||x_n-x_m||=\sqrt 2$ for $n\ne m$, so $(x_n)$ cannot have a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 2):

This is false in general. Consider $X = \ell_2$. Then $X^\ast$ is separable and the sequence $(e_n)$ with

$$e_n = (\dots, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, \dots)$$

(with $1$ on the $n$-th position) is a bounded one which clearly does not have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Can we say that $ \{x_n \} $ admits a weakly convergent subsequence ?

Comment: I think this is also not true in general. It is true if $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: @Jan indeed, it is not true in general: the unit basis $(e_n)$ of $\ell_1$  cannot have any norm-convergent or weak-convergent subsequences, since weak-convergent and norm-convergent sequences in $\ell_1$ agree.